# What is the meaning of ::class in config/app.php provider array in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Hi i dont know why we are using `::class` in laravel 5 `config/app.php` provider array like `Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class` what is the purpose of `::class` and what kind of other things we can use in same manner as `::class` is being used here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the fully qualified name (meaning, along with the namespaces) of the class as string. You can have a look here: [PHP: The Basics - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class)